# Running command from Java code doesn't work, but same string works manually through cmd.exe

Tags: java, cmd, runtime

I'm launching from my jar 3 programs with their own parameters.
First and second programs do their job, but not the second one.

Here the code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String cmdGet= "something";
try    {
            infolog("Executing command: " + cmdGet);
            rt.exec(cmdGet);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            infolog("Unable to launch program 2");
            saveLog();
        }
```

Here the command for something

```
D:\Root\Module\Translators\L2Fo\SE_Draft_Update.exe -se_file="F:\Disp\Stage\DC\Ude34ea24x591ecb1c412x\M8486.dft" -input_file="F:\Disp\Stage\DC\Ude34ea24x591ecb1c412x\result\AttributeFile_M8486.txt" -log_file="F:\Disp\Stage\DC\Ude34ea24x591ecb1c412x\result\SELogg_M8486.txt"
```

In the log I find the proper command launched, but I see that its jobs are not done. So by copying the string manually in the cmd prompt it works

The third program after this one works too.
I do not understand why.

Comment: Anything in the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this might be relevant to the path, where you are trying to run your program from. If you execute it from jar it might not work, try to test it with absolute path

Comment: If you have more commands working with this approach, it is possible that the problem is not related to the java code, but to the command being executed. Why don't you post the *`cmd`* command?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered without the specific command being run.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. There is no command `something` in cmd, so I'm guessing that's not the actual command you're trying to run.

Comment: Just added the cmd code, anything in the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a command needs its own cmd-shell. 
Then you had to add a "CMD.EXE /C " prefix. This is the reason why
the 'something' line works fine in the cmd-Window.

```
if (b_shell == true) cmd = "CMD.EXE /C " + cmdstr;
else                 cmd = cmdstr; 
...
rt.exec(cmd);
```

I pass the b_shell as argument to a wrapper method:

```
public static void systemCall(String cmdstr,boolean b_shell,Path logfile) throws IOException
```

Comment: I've tried this way but nothing. Also tried passing the cmd to a batch file but nothing (with and without "CMD.EXE /C "

Comment: I've tried all kind of solutions, including administrator permission through manifest (also if I was in doubt on that because the user had already the needed privileges for using the exe). What I've checked right now is that the command with dynamic variables doesn't work as the question posted, but the same command with static string inside java code works ! I get the command from the log, so I think it's ok

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that answer, perhaps you like to try a version which
is able to wait for the terminating command and returns the output of the command as an ArrayList.

```
/**
 * Executes command 'cmdstr'. The output of the command is stored in a ArrayList-String array
 * @param cmdstr The command line to be executed not containing  a redirect to an outputfile ( &gt; x.txt )
 * @param b_wait If true the command waits until it is finished and 'errmsg' contains the exit value
 * @param b_shell If true the command will be started in a shell (uses prefix CMD.EXE /C)
 * @param errmsg OUT: Error message
 * @return ArrayList-String output or null on error, see errmsg
 * @since Last change: 2014.04.30         
 */ 
public static ArrayList<String> systemCallOutputArray(String cmdstr,boolean b_wait,boolean b_shell,/*IO*/StringBuffer errmsg)  
{ 
final String fn="systemCallOutputArray()"; 
    errmsg.setLength(0);
    if (cmdstr == null || cmdstr.isEmpty()) {  errmsg.append(fn + ": Invalid arg. 'cmdstr' (null or empty)");  return null; }

    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    String cmd ="";

try
{
     int exit_value = -1;
     Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p = r.exec(cmd);  

     String line="";
     if (b_wait == true) 
     {       
        p.waitFor(); // waits until prozess is terminated, throws InterruptedException if wait is interrupted      

        exit_value = p.exitValue();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));      
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        { if (line.isEmpty() == false) output.add(line); 
        }      
        input.close();
        return output;        
     } 
     // the following lines are for b_wait = false

     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));      
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
     { if (line.isEmpty() == false) output.add(line); 
     }      
     input.close();      
     return output;               
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{   
    errmsg.append(fn + " failed: " + e.toString() + " cmd: '" + cmd + "'");   
    return null;
}    
} //---------------- end of systemCallOutputArray()
```